# Adding a single column of only one value( eg: Experiment condition name) to multiple csv files in a single folder

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a folder with multiple csv files,I want to add one column with the name of the experiment condition to all the csv files in the folder.

```
import os, pandas as pd
import csv
file_list = list()
os.chdir('.....name.../')
g=[]
for file in os.listdir():
    if file.endswith('.csv'):
        df = pd.read_csv(file)
        df['Condition'] = "After food"
        file_list.append(df)
        g.append(file_list)
```

Comment: What is your question here? What is not working?

Comment: love the username btw =)

Comment: @MyNameIsCaleb the code is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're already in the correct directory we can try something like this :

first we pass all the csv files into a list

```
files = glob.glob('*.csv')
```

we can then iterate through this list to find your columns with a handy `try` and `except` statement.

```
for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    try:
        df['Condition'] == "After food"
        # do something.
        df.to_csv(f'{file}.csv',index=False)
        print(f'{file} has been altered')
    except KeyError:
        print(f'{file} has not met the condition, therefore has not been changed.')
    except EmptyDataError:
        print(f"this {file} has no data to parse")
```

the output will be something like this :

```
PayCodes.csv has been altered
birmingham.csv has not met the condition
CF44.csv has not met the condition
DE11.csv has not met the condition
Dublin.csv has not met the condition
DY8.csv has not met the condition
```

Comment: the same error EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file

Comment: @mashedpoteto you can handle that with another except statement, see edited answer.

Comment: This is working,but i's not changing the file in teh folder.It's printing the file has been altered,but there is additional column added to the files in the folders

Comment: You need to change your path try printing `os.getcwd` and change your directory if need be the files are most likely being saved to the same location as your python program

Comment: ```
import csv,os
import pandas as pd
os.chdir('/Desktop/folder')
PATH = os.getcwd()+ "/Desktop/folder/"
files = glob.glob('*.csv')

for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    try:
        df['Condition'] == "After food"
        # do something.
        df.to_csv(f'{file}.csv',index=False)
        print(f'{file} has been altered')
    except KeyError:
        print(f'{file} has not met the condition, therefore has not been changed.')
    except EmptyDataError:
        print(f"this {file} has no data to parse")

```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, your problem is saving back to the csv files.
If you want to do that, you can use the function to_csv in your loop function:

```
df.to_csv(file)
```

Tell me if that wasn't what you meant and I'll try to help you.

Comment: @Gligo I tried it,I am getting the error as EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file